# How do I properly configure Razer DeathAdder 3500 DPI on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, razer-mouse

So I have a [Razer DeathAdder](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169416100).
And I'm using Mac OS, the problem is that I can't configure it properly...

I need Button 3 to function as a middle button that supports scrolling.
Button 4: Forward, Button 5: Back.

[image]

Do you have a config file for these options? Or any other ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

Install [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive) and you'll be able to tame your mouse, so it fully meets your needs:

> The USB Overdrive is a device driver for Mac OS X that handles any USB mouse / trackball / joystick / gamepad / media keyboard and any Bluetooth mouse from any manufacturer and lets you configure them either globally or on a per-application, per-device basis.
>
> It works in Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger), 10.5 (Leopard) and 10.6 (Snow Leopard) in both 32-bit & 64-bit.
>
> It reads all kinds of wheels, buttons, switches and controls and assigns them to useful actions like clicking, typing, scrolling, launching, opening documents and so forth. The USB Overdrive can easily handle several USB devices at once and can assign different settings to each one.
>
> Please note that the current version 3.0.1 is newer than version 10.4.8 even though obviously 3 is smaller than 10. I went back to a more standard version numbering scheme after I found out that trying to match the current OS number was very confusing for end users.

Comment: Works very smoothly for razer atheris as well!

Answer (score 4):

Select button 4.

Keyboard shortcut.

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Select button 5.

Keyboard shortcut.

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Select "Pass Through" option in the Razer DeathAdder application for button 3 to act as "Middle Click", and for Forward and Back.

The Razer app provides those options under "Advanced Functions" for each of those buttons.

Select them and click on Apply, OK.

Don't need to quit the App or restart Mac. Nothing! Works instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but I found a way. Configure your mouse on a windows computer to the key bindings you want for mac.

The mouse will remember the keybindings and input them when connected to mac.

You may need to change the keys you use on your mac, to suit the "windows input".
Ie if you want to use button 4 for "cmd + V" to paste something. You are going to have to assign a new shortcut in your keyboard settings on your mac (System preferences > Keyboard > Shortcut > Assesability > +) then assign the keys your mouse is outputting.

You can also find out the exact output key your mouse is sending to your mac via a program called Karabiner - Eventviewer. This will help you reverse engineer the mouse keybindings.